# Open Blob file in print window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a blob file for print. It is working fine with the pop up if the code is not commented, but I need to open it in the print window.

```
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
//window.open(fileURL, 'popup', 'width=auto,height=700');

myWindow = window.open(fileURL);
myWindow.document.close();
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
```

Comment: you want to print without calling popup window?

Comment: I know how to print with the pop up, but I was hoping that I could call the print window without the pop up